# Differential form in a variety, from definition and properties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, co-tangent-space

Following Shafarevich Reid - Basic algebraic geometry 1, the differential at $p$ of a polynomial $F(T_1,\dots,T_n)$ is the linear part of the Taylor expansion at $x$ (p. 87), so
$$ (dF=)d_xF=\sum \frac{\partial F}{\partial T_i}(T_i-p_i).$$
This is an object of $\Theta_x^*$, the dual of the tangent space.

Later, on p. 190, it is defined as a 1-form something that is generated, at some open set $U$, by differentials of polynomials as $k[U]$-submodule of the module of maps from $x\in X$ to $\Theta_x^*$.

For example, in $\mathbb{A}^n$ with coordinates $y_1,\dots,y_n$,
$$ d_p y_i = y_i - p_i$$
is a 1-form. We still have this if we consider the curve $y^2=x^3+x$. We can deduce that
$ 2ydy= (3x^2+1)dx $ as a relation in $\Theta^*$: at any point $(p,q)$ in the curve we should have
$$ 2q(y-q)=(3p^2+1)(x-p),$$
precisely the equation of the tangent space, so it is true in $\Theta_{(p,q)}^*$ (right?).

**My question** is in the projective cases and the relations between the coverings (I guess).

(i) $\mathbb{P}^1$ with the covering $\mathbb{A}^1_0\cup \mathbb{A}^1_1$ and variables $u,t$. We have the relation $u=t^{-1}$ in the intersection $\mathbb{A}^1_0\cap \mathbb{A}^1_1$. How do we end up with $du=-dt/t^2$? If this were true, then by definition
$$ u-p = \frac{-(t-1/p)}{1/p^2} $$
at the point $[1:p]$, which seems not true.

(ii)Another example I am struggling with is the following relation $\phi=\psi=\chi$, how do we deduce that with the definition $d_{point}y=y-point_y$?

[image]

Comment: For (i), just differentiate. Since $ut = 1$, taking the exterior derivative on both sides yields $udt + tdu = 0$. Solving we get $du = -(u/t)dt = -(1/t^2)dt$.

Comment: That is my problem, There is no exterior derivative here, only the linear part of the Taylor expansion.

Anyways I found my misunderstanding, if there is no reply in some time I think I will answer it myself.